# How do the toxicities of arsenate and arsenite compare?

Tags: redox, biochemistry, toxicity

So I was browsing the [detoxification metabolistic mechanisms](https://ecocyc.org/overviewsWeb/celOv.shtml#) for *E. coli*, and came across an [arsenic detoxification mechanism](https://ecocyc.org/ECOLI/NEW-IMAGE?object=RXN-982) that converted [arsenate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arsenate) to arsenite using a [glutaredoxin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glutaredoxin). So my question is, how does the toxicity of arsenate compare to arsenite? And what is the use of this pathway in *E. coli*?

Comment: that's weird because I found a source that says arsenite is more toxic than arsenate. (ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3183630/ see introduction). That might be for humans though.

Comment: @S.Chevalier I think that it can go both ways, but your point is interesting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see now.

According to the same website with the reaction mechanism,

> Although the arsenite formed is more toxic than arsenate , it can be extruded from some bacteria by EC 3.6.3.16 , arsenite-transporting ATPase; in other organisms, arsenite can be methylated by EC 2.1.1.137 , arsenite methyltransferase, in a pathway that produces non-toxic organoarsenical compounds. cf EC 1.20.4.4, arsenate reductase (thioredoxin) .